# Does a 3D line intersect with a surface?

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, geometry

*Background:* I need to write an application that determines whether a line intersects with a surface in 3D space. The application is to scan window surfaces in a building, look in the direction of the sun at a given date and time, and determine whether the sun will be visible or obscured by any external obstacle.

I already have the sun direction in azimuth and elevation, and all windows and obstacles are defined in 3D space (X/Y/Z). I can also map that 3D space with the sun's azimuth. I also know how to detect inside and outside surfaces of a window to know if the sun is shining in or out of the window.

*Problem:* Now what's missing is an algorithm or C# code function that determines whether that line intersects with any tested obstacle surface (or a line from a scan point on the inner window surface goes through the outer window surface).

All surfaces are aligned at the X, Y or Z axis plane, there are no free rotations. (Complex real-world obstacles can be replaced by simpler geometries.) I design my world in OpenSCAD to have a visualisation, but then parse the relevant instructions to extract the coordinates.

The azimuth 0° (North) is defined to point to the positive Y axis, 90° (East) goes to the positive X axis, and so on.

Something like this:

```cs
struct Point3D
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
}

struct Surface
{
    // TODO
}

struct Cube
{
    // Origin point
    public double X0;
    public double Y0;
    public double Z0;
    // Dimensions along axes
    public double DX;
    public double DY;
    public double DZ;
}

bool IsSunVisible(Point3D pov, double azimuth, double elevation, Cube[] obstacles)
{
    foreach (var obstacle in obstacles)
    {
        var sides = GetCubeSides(obstacle);
        foreach (var side in sides)
        {
            if (LineIntersectsSurface(pov, azimuth, elevation, side))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool LineIntersectsSurface(Point3D origin, double azimuth, double elevation, Surface surface)
{
    // TODO: return true or false
}

Surface[] GetCubeSides(Cube cube)
{
    // TODO: Reduce the cube to its four vertical side surfaces
    // (the top and bottom side are not relevant here but still acceptable)
}
```

I've seen similar questions with solutions for Java or Python but I don't understand the data types used there. And I've seen purely mathematical questions with solutions that contain large matrixes that I don't know what to do with. I know basic trigonometry so I could determine angles based on the axis plane and implement it with many similar switch/cases but there must be a more elegant solution than that.

Many people also talk about ray tracing but that seems to be something different. It look from one point in all directions to project 3D to 2D. But I look from many points in a single direction and just need to know if there's something, not create a projection of it.

Comment: Although a ray tracer typically traces rays for each pixel, however you can use the same concept and also trace a ray in this scenario.

Construct a ray based on the two given points, and test them against all the planes to see if there are any intersections.

It will also be easier if you already convert the azimuth and elevation into a 3D point.

Comment: I wrote a line/plane intersection a while ago, you can see it here: https://github.com/darkeclipz/finite-plane-line-segment-intersection/blob/master/LineBoundedPlaneIntersection/Program.cs.

However, if you lack the knowledge of vector math, I'd suggest to use a library such as https://github.com/gradientspace/geometry3Sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Möller-Trumbore algorithm is (i think) the fastest ray/triangle intersection algorithm.
It is quite easy to implement, here is one implementation.
You'll just have to define a Ray structure withe Origin and Direction.
And then pass each faces.

The HitTestResult is a personal class, you can implement your own.

```
public static HitTestResult HitTestFace(HitRay ray, vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2, float Eupsilon = MathHelper.Eupsilon108)
    {
        var result = new HitTestResult();
        var edge1 = v1 - v0;
        var edge2 = v2 - v0;
        var n = ray.Direction.Cross(edge2);
        var det = edge1.Dot(n);
        // if the determinant is negative the triangle is backfacing
        // if the determinant is close to 0, the ray misses the triangle
        if (det < Eupsilon &&
            det > -Eupsilon)
            return result;
        var f = 1.0f / det;
        var s = ray.Origin - v0;
        float u = f * (s.Dot(n));
        if (u < -Eupsilon ||
            u > 1.0f)
            return result;
        var q = s.Cross(edge1);
        var v = f * ray.Direction.Dot(q);
        if (v < -Eupsilon ||
            u + v > 1.0f)
            return result;
        // At this stage we can compute t to find out where the intersection point is on the line.
        var t = f * edge2.Dot(q);
        if (t > Eupsilon) // ray intersection
        {
            result.HasHitFacet = true;
            result.MinDistance = t;
            result.HitPointModelSpace = ray.Origin + t * ray.Direction;
        }
        return result;
    }
```